# Query about C.E./A.D. and B.C./B.C.E

Tags: meaning, religion

I know the difference between A.D./B.C. and C.E./B.C.E. in terms of the religious accuracy i.e. that Christ was probably born in 4 B.C., what I don't understand is how this affects the C.E./B.C.E. interpretation of the calendar.

Comment: It doesn't. _B.C./B.C.E_  just shifts the counting from Christ to the Christian Era, which is independent of anybody's birth date.

Comment: @JohnLawler, CE would normally stand for "Common Era" rather than "Christian Era". AFAIK, the whole point was to try & introduce a secular term rather than the existing religious ones.

Comment: @JohnLawler - "Common", not "Christian". They're functionally identical, but the CE/BCE usage was specifically intended to dissociate the dating system from any particular religion or religious figure.

Comment: Practically speaking, the `C` part was chosen because it subliminally associates _Common_ with _Christian_, so nobody has to pretend it stands for either one.

Comment: @anotherdave: I would argue that it has achieved the opposite. It now connects Christianity to being common, which now attaches "B.C.E" to the predominantly Christian world. By comparison, labeling the date by Christ's (alleged) birth is more objective. Someone raised in a non-Christian environment would more likely agree that Christ is reported to have been born then, compared to considering the advent of Christianity as the common era.

Comment: @flater but it's Christ's alleged birth date in the common calendar that we all us (as opposed to the Islamic calendar, Jewish calendar, etc.) — so I don't think it's trying to deny the fact that it maps directly to AD/BC. In the same way that UTC is Greenwich Mean Time, but they wanted a name less bound to an individual timezone as the standard.

Comment: @anotherdave "in the common calendar that we all us (as opposed to the Islamic calendar, Jewish calendar, etc.)" That is correct for you and me, but not regions where the Jewish or Islamic calendar are the predominant calendar. And that's the point, it is only correct in the context of the predominantly Christian world (or those whose culture is still mostly based on having been a Christian region). The alleged birth of Christ is more universal (even if you don't believe in Christ) compared to _labeling the Christian calendar as commonplace._

Comment: @flater *"it is only correct in the context of the predominantly Christian world (or those whose culture is still mostly based on having been a Christian region)"* — [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar), only Iran, Afghanistan and Ethiopia are named as countries that do not use the Gregorian calendar as (at least one of) their civil calendar(s). It's also the de facto international standard. In that sense, I think it's fair to say that it's "common" (which also doesn't imply universal) without doing any disservice to other systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar is the same in each system.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era):

> The two notation systems are numerically equivalent; thus "2017 CE" corresponds to "AD 2017" and "400 BCE" corresponds to "400 BC".